# Returning matching or highest row in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to retrieve only two rows when joining these two table.

In table A: I have an ID and Date

In table B: I have an ID and Timestamp.

My select is retrieving 4 rows, however, I want to pick the timestamp from table B that matches the Date from table A (Condition 1). When two Dates are found (Condition 2), I want to pick the one with the most recent timestamp.

Here's the model:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.TIMESTAMP FROM A, B
WHERE A.ID  = B.ID
```

Table A

```
ID         ||  Date 
1          ||  09/17/2016
2          ||  02/02/2016
```

TABLE B

```
ID||TIMESTAMP
1 || 17-SEP-16 12.50.40.754543000 PM
1 || 19-SEP-16 12.56.40.754543000 PM
2 || 02-FEB-08 10.31.36.154000000 PM
2 || 02-FEB-08 10.31.32.284000000 PM
```

Results

```
ID   ||  TIMESTAMP
1    ||  17-SEP-16 12.50.40.754543000 PM
2    ||  02-FEB-08 10.31.36.154000000 PM
```

Comment: Learn to use a proper JOIN. When you feel the need to type a comma in your FROM statement, it's a signal that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Even when using a JOIN, the select will still return two rows, but the comparison should only return one. SELECT B.TIMESTAMP FROM B JOIN A ON A.ID = B.ID

Comment: [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Data set added to post

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, 
       B.TIMESTAMP 
FROM B
join a 
  on a.id = b.id
   and a.time_stamp = (select max(timestamp), id from b group by id)
```

Comment: Thanks. This will definitely work if I want to select the MAX only. However, in this case, what if I want to check whether A.DATE = B.TIMESTAMP first, if there was one match, I would pick that.But, If there were more than one match, then pick the one with the most recent timestamp. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
 ID Int,
 Date Date
)

CREATE TABLE TABLE2
(
ID int,
Timestamp Datetime
)

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1,'09/17/2001')
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(1,'09/17/2001 12:10:12.013')
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(1,'09/17/2001 12:15:15.015')
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(1,'09/17/2001 12:18:15.015')
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(1,'09/17/2001 12:25:15.015')

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
SELECT * FROM TABLE2

SELECT A.ID, C.Timestamp
  FROM TABLE1 AS A 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(B.Timestamp) AS Timestamp
                FROM TABLE2 AS B
              WHERE A.ID = B.ID) AS C
```

Comment: Thanks. your query selects the MAX timestamp in either case. I have updated the tables sample image in the initial post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for oldest date-time from same ID. You could try below example.

```
SELECT A.ID, MIN(B.TIMESTAMP) AS TIMESTAMP FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID  = B.ID GROUP BY A.ID
```

Comment: The query selects the MIN for both IDs. I was hoping to find exact match for ID 1 and MAX for ID 2. I posted table example screenshot in the initial post. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by *"exact match for ID 1 and MAX for ID 2 ?"* what if there are multiple rows, may be ID 3, 4.. ??

Comment: For example, For ID 1, the query should look for the matching timestamp first, if the query finds one matching timestamp, then it selects that timestamp. if the query finds two matching timestamps, then it picks the most recent timestamp. I put an example of the results set in the initial post image. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this query,

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Date, C.ID , CONVERT(VARCHAR,C.Timestamp,100) AS Timestam
  FROM TABLE1 AS A 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID,MAX(B.Timestamp) AS Timestamp
                FROM TABLE2 AS B 
              WHERE A.ID = B.ID GROUP BY ID) AS C
```

Comment: The query is still selecting the MAX timestamp for both IDs. For ID: 1, I should be selecting 17-SEP-16 12.50.40.754543000 PM as a stamp and for ID: 2, 02-FEB-08 10.31.36.154000000 PM. I posted an updated tables example in the initial post. Thanks

Comment: There is no `convert()` in Oracle (I also fail to see why converting the timestamp is needed in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in two steps. First you need to join on the condition that the date component of the timestamp matches the date in table A. You didn't say what should happen if there is no matching timestamp in table B, if that is even possible in your real-life data. In the solution below I assume you don't want such rows (from table A) to appear in the result set at all. If your requirement is different, say so and perhaps the solution can be adapted.

Then you need to group by ID and select the max timestamp. In the solution below I assume ID is a unique key in table A. If instead you may have multiple rows with the same ID in table A, with different Dates, then the solution would need to be modified based on your FULL requirement; most likely, DATE would have to be added to the GROUP BY clause.

The solution assumes Date is a pure date (with time component equal to 00:00:00).

NOTE: I didn't use "timestamp" and "date" as column names; they are reserved keywords and shouldn't be used as column names. I used ts and dt instead.

```
select   a.id, max(b.ts) as ts
from     a inner join b
         on a.id = b.id and b.ts >= a.dt and b.ts < a.dt + 1
group by a.id
;
```